# How to set STUN servers in JsSIP 3.3.0

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, stun, jssip

I'm trying to set up a webapp using `JsSIP` 3.3.0 connection to a `Asterisk` server.
I can find some documentation regarding `TURN` servers in an old version (0.3.0), but apparently this feature was removed in version 0.6.0.
I also found this: https://github.com/versatica/JsSIP/issues/449, but this is from version 3.0.0, and I can't anything regarding this for version 3.3.0.

My problem is that I can make a call from `JsSIP` through `Asterisk` via `WebRTC` to my cellphone, but I'm missing the sound from the cellphone - the other way the sound is fine.

Anyone?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with TURN servers, as Iñaki Baz Castillo mentions.
I needed to "link" the audio stream to an Audio object, like this:

```
sipAudio = new Audio();         
session = coolPhone.call(phone_number, options);            
session.connection.onaddstream = function(e){
    sipAudio.srcObject = e.stream;
    sipAudio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can perfectly set STUN and TURN servers in the pcConfig option on both ua.call() and session.answer(), so check the doc.

Anyway, don't assume your problem with incoming calls in Asterisk is due to lack of TURN. It's not. Find the problem first and the solution later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
First: sorry, but I'm very new to JsSIP, and unless you read the entire docs, it's pretty hard to find anything (no search function), if you don't know just where to look (Google gives me nothing on 3.3.0 neither on "TURN" nor "pcConfig").
I read somewhere (of course I can't find it now), at wiki.asterisk.org, that if there was problems with no sound at all, or only sound in one direction, you should look at TURN servers.

Comment: It wasn't at wiki.asterisk.org, but at freepbx: https://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FPG/WebRTC+Phone-UCP#WebRTCPhone-UCP-EnablingWebRTC - in the bottom it says that about TURN servers. So that's why I was looking that way.
What else do you think I should look at?

Comment: If you have proper bidirectional audio when JsSIP receives an INVITE but don't have bidirectional audio in the other direction, that's not a lack of TURN issue.

Comment: You're right, it had nothing to do with TURN servers.